# Docker Compose deploy to ECS cannot resolve service names (YELB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'my deploying a simple Compose file with a Flask app server talking to PSQL database in another container; works locally fine.

When using the new-ish Docker Compose deploy to ECS context, it fails: the app server cannot DNS resolve the name of the "psql" server. I see it created a CloudMap with entries for my service name, but to no avail.

`Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d`

So I followed YELB tutorial by @mreferre (https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/), and it also deployed locally, but failed on "docker compose up":

`YelbuiService    CREATE_FAILED   Resource creation cancelled`

I see in his `docker-compose.yml` this critical note:

```
  networks:
    yelb-network:
      driver: bridge # a user defined bridge is required; the default bridge network doesn't support name resolution
```

But everything I've read says that Compose to ECS uses FARGATE, and that requires an `awsvpc` network, not a `bridge`. And before it disappeared, the AWS console showed my YELB Tasks were using `awsvpc` networks, not `bridge`.

I defined a bridge network in my Flask/PSQL app anyway and did another `docker compose up` and noticed this (which probably scrolled off my YELB screen):

```
  WARNING networks.driver: unsupported attribute
```

So it seems `awsvpc` does NOT support Service Discovery by DNS resolution, and we cannot use `bridge` for Docker to ECS, so I'm stuck.

Or am I missing something?

Do I have to use the separate `ecs-cli` tools to deploy my Compose file? It's a lot more hairy than the sweet `docker compose up` we know and love, and requires me to do a lot more work.

Any other guidance?

Thanks for your help.

My repo in progress is at https://github.com/shentonfreude/compose-ecs-flask-psql
but for convenience the `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: "3"                    # ECS may not like decimal suffix"

x-aws-logs_retention: 7
x-aws-vpc: vpc-01234567890123456 # in ue1


networks:
  # YELB says: user defined bridge required; default bridge network doesn't support name resolution
  flasknet:
    driver: bridge 

services:

  psql:
    container_name: psql
    image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER:     flaskapp
      POSTGRES_DB:       flaskapp
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: flaskapp
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready --username=flaskapp && psql --username=flaskapp --list"
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - flasknet

  flaskapp:
    container_name: flaskapp
    image: 314159265358.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cshenton/flaskapp:latest
    environment:
      # Neither bare service "psql",
      # FQDN "psql.psql.compose-ecs-flask-psql.local",
      # nor awsvpc "localhost" work.
      DB_HOST:     psql
      DB_PORT:     5432
      DB_NAME:     flaskapp
      DB_PASSWORD: flaskapp
      DB_USER:     flaskapp
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      psql:
        condition: service_healthy
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: 512M
    networks:
      - flasknet
```

Answer (score 2):

@mreferre here :)

Thanks for trying this out.

First and foremost bridge is the right thing to use. Docker will do its magic to do the mapping from bridge to awsvpc as part of the integration (much like they map a compose service to an ECS service etc). IIRC the warning message is just because you can't use alternative drivers so they just ignore the entry (and since bridge is the default you could remove that line and it will do the same mapping - with the bonus that you won't see the warning).

As per the `psql` name not being resolved, that's weird. The compose integration should build the correct wiring (yes using CloudMap etc) so that each service can resolve every other service by its name. In other words the `flaskapp` service should be able to resolve the `psql` service.

This is the mechanism I use in Yelb so that the app server can connect to `yelb-db` (which is the hard coded endpoint in the app server code).

I can't test your app cause I don't have your app container. But am I reading it right that you can't even compose up my yelb compose file ([link](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/deployments/platformdeployment/Docker/docker-compose.yaml)). That would be weird as that should work out of the box locally and on ECS.

[UPDATE 1] I can confirm that the problem is related to your VPC configuration (or at least it's not related to the compose syntax you are using). I have cloned your repo and composed up your app (worked fine locally). I then pushed the image into my ECR account and edited your compose file in two ways: 1) to point to my ECR image and 2) commented out the `x-aws-vpc` entry (this forces compose to use the default VPC in your account). When I composed it up in the ECS context it deployed on aws and using the ALB link created I could use the `createtable`, `insert` and `select` APIs just fine.

Can you try remove the `x-aws-vpc` entry and confirm we can pin down to it the root of the problem? We can figure out why later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and support for Docker and ECS here on SO.
I put a link to my little repo, if you wanna build the image and try it out. 
But since I wasn't able to get Yelb to run, I am concerned that maybe there is something wrong with my VPC environment and its 2 public subnets -- possible? (a single container with a Service is accessible via the ALB so connectivity seems OK)
In the AWS web UI, is there anything I can be looking for to validate that 'bridge' is in use, and examine CloudMap connectivity?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes I would not move onto debugging your app until you get Yelb up and running. If you just download my Yelb compose file and `docker compose up` it without tweaking the VPC etc... does it deploy correctly and can you use the app (which would mean that `yelb-db` is reachable and discoverable)? If that setup doesn't work it means you may have some issue at the account level (because by default it use the default VPC).

Comment: I have updated the answer with additional content.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I think our account is so old it predates the Default VPC (we started with what is now EC2 Classic). If I can't find an account with a default VPC, I'll create a new account and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: I had to create a new AWS account since my others are older, and was able to deploy my stack into the default VPC -- w00t!

I then tried creating a new VPC (2 public subnets, IGW, default route through IGW) when when I deployed into this VPC by name, it failed -- disappearing too quickly to get logs, but was not able to get the app service to start "essential container in task exited". 

Do you have a CloudFormation template to create a default-like VPC that I can test? Our Security folks remove default VPCs even when we have them, so I want to create anew.
Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to deploy your compose with a custom (existing) VPC ("2 public subnets, IGW, default route through IGW"). The IaC piece that created it is somewhat large and hard to share but it's just a very simple VPC. It would be interesting to dive deeper into the error you are getting and where it breaks for you. Can you re-run it and report the exact behavior?

Comment: Good news, found out that we MUST have `EnabldDnsHostnames: true` on the VPC, else Service Discovery by DNS names don't work.  I've updated my GH repo with a CloudFormation that creates a working VPC, and the docs with clear instructions to deploy.

Also tested that I don't need Yelb's `network... bridge` either, which makes sense if Fargate is really `awsvpc` always. 

Maybe add some AWS Docs that indicate what VPC settings must be enabled?

Thanks again for all your help and insights. Really looking forward to more Compose->ECS deploys like this.

Comment: Awesome! Happy it worked out! Thanks for the suggestions on how to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

As @mreferre points out the `compose up` works fine with an Default VPC, however early (2013) accounts don't have this, and many organizations remove these.

You can create a new VPC, get the name, and set it in your Compose file like `x-aws-vpc: vpc-deadc0decafebeef`.

But you MUST have one feature turned on in the VPC for DNS to resolve the Compose service names: `EnableDnsHostnames: true`. Without this, an app server (for example) will not be able to resolve its database server.

Below is a minimal CloudFormation for a VPC with 2 public subnets (required by the ALB):

```
# VPC with IGW, Default Route, 2 public subnets.
# VPC must EnableDnsHostnames for Fargate Service Discovery by Docker service name.
# Subnets do not need MapPublicIpOnLaunch.

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true  # critical for Service Discovery
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-VPC" ]]
  InetGW:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-IGW" ]]
  VPCGWAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InetGW
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-RouteTable" ]]
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InetGW
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable

  Subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/20
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-Subnet1" ]]
  Subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs ]
      CidrBlock: 10.0.16.0/20
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::StackName", "-Subnet2" ]]

  Subnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet1
  Subnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet2

Outputs:
  VpcID:
    Description: The ID of the created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
```

Comment: Tracked here: https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/2024